# How can I get a scatter plot from this df? First I need to sum the occurrence for each product category

Tags: python, pandas

```py
prod_categ1 = data_test.groupby(['Product_Category_1','Product_ID'])\
.agg({'Product_Category_3':'count'})\
.rename(columns={'Product_Category_3':'prod_categ1'})

prod_categ1
```

I have grouped the 3 categories and I want to have a total for each category before I can do the plot.

Comment: What did you try yourself? What problems did you run into? Can you share your code?

Comment: Please show us an honest attempt and provide an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).